# How to call fragment from a class in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity in which a button ,when button is clicked I want to call fragment on click logout,How can I do That.Its gives throws error like...

Here is my code

```
public class CLoginSessionManagement {
// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String s_szKEY_MOBILE = "agentCode";
// Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String s_szKEY_PASSWORD = "pin";
// Sharedpref file name
private static final String s_szPREF_NAME = "LoginData";
// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String s_szIS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
public SharedPreferences m_LoginPref;
public Editor m_Editor;
public Context m_Context;
public int n_PrivateMode = 0;

// Constructor
public CLoginSessionManagement(Context m_Context) {
    this.m_Context = m_Context;
    m_LoginPref = m_Context.getSharedPreferences(s_szPREF_NAME, n_PrivateMode);
    m_Editor = m_LoginPref.edit();
}

// Registeration Session Management....
public void setLoginData(String mobile, String pin) {
    m_Editor.putBoolean(s_szIS_LOGIN, true);
    m_Editor.putString(s_szKEY_MOBILE, mobile);
    m_Editor.putString(s_szKEY_PASSWORD, pin);
    m_Editor.commit();
}

/**
 * checkLogin() session wil check user Login status
 * If false it will redirect user to Login page
 * Else won't do anything
 */
public boolean checkLogin() {
    if (!isLogin()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, CMainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        m_Context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get stored Login session data
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getLoginDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
    // user name
    user.put(s_szKEY_MOBILE, m_LoginPref.getString(s_szKEY_MOBILE, null));
    // user email id
    user.put(s_szKEY_PASSWORD, m_LoginPref.getString(s_szKEY_PASSWORD, null));
    // return user
    return user;
}

public boolean isLogin() {
    return m_LoginPref.getBoolean(s_szIS_LOGIN, false);
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 */
public void logoutUser() {
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    m_Editor.clear();
    m_Editor.commit();
    Fragment m_oLoginScreen = new CLoginScreen();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, m_oLoginScreen, null);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

Gives me error at getSupportfragmentManager in LogOut section.
here is my code from where a click event

```
else if (id == R.id.LogOut) {
        s_oCloginSession.checkLogin();
        s_oCloginSession.logoutUser();
        Fragment m_oLoginScreen = new CLoginScreen();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, m_oLoginScreen, null);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: What error do you see? Paste the exception from log.

Comment: Does your class have the method getSupportFragmentManager? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the error do you see?

Comment: cannot resolve  method getsupportfragmentManager

Comment: see I have a class MainActivity and have button in that class when I click button i want to call login fragment for which code is written above

Comment: I already use context but gives me error

Comment: I have edited my code check it out it will work

Comment: you have to cast it to the right type of activity. FragmentActivity or AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your class does not have the method that you are trying to call getSupportFragmentManager.

if your context in this class is a activity that extends a class with this method you can use

```
((AppCompactActivity)m_Context).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

if not, you have two choices, make your activity class extends AppCompactActivity or use getFragmentManager instead.

Comment: you can access it from context you have to convert it to Activity and then access it

Comment: If it helped could you mark it as a answer and/or upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

Either try getFragmentManager() instead or extend AppCompatActivity class for your Activity.

Comment: use getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call getSupportFragmnetManager only from inside activity extended classes like AppcombatActvity or FragmentActivity. To get support fragment manager from other classes make use of the context of the application. Replace

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

with

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = ((<activity_name>)m_Context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: but what about non activity class

Comment: I want to call from non actiuvity class

Comment: You can either type cast the context into activity or you can pass the activity as an argument and call the support fragment manager from it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access **getSupportFragmentManager()** as your Class doesn't extend Activity.If you want to access the method the method in a non Activity class. Taking that context passed is a Activity you can call the method like this:

```
final Activity activity = (Activity) context;

    activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```

ThankYou I hope this was helpful.

Comment: You converted context to activity?

Comment: what are you passing into the constructor as the context? It needs to be an activity reference i.e. when calling the constructor from an Activity you would pass in `this` (the activity reference you need) and it should work as above answer. `It still doesn't work?` isn't to helpful especially as people are trying help you - do you get a `ClassCastException` ?

Comment: (Context mContext)

Comment: Yep i agree with that and I have also mentioned it in my answer

Comment: Nitin make sure context is an activity

Answer (score 0):

I think right way is user interface in your java class and implement that in your activity
Here is example using interface
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qirpdnd78xlbnzh/SamplePro_with_interface%27.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
             FragmentManager  mFragmentManager = (activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
    // if getSupportFragmentManager() doesnt work try with getFragmentManager and change the import of fragment
             FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new CLoginScreen());
                 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                 getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public static void  t(Activity activity){
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastId);

}
```